# How can I register SCDF app with microk8s?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, microk8s

I have installed `SCDF` in a `microk8s` cluster. Ubuntu runs in VirtualBox.
Now I'm trying to register a custom app in SCDF.
My app is build as a Docker image (myorg/myapp:latest) and registered in a private local registry (localhost:5000).

I followed the microk8s documentation here https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-private
and add my Docker registry in the `containerd-template.toml` file :

```
[plugins.cri.registry.mirrors."myorg"]
  endpoint = ["http://localhost:5000"]
```

But now I can't figure out how to register my app in SCDF.
When I try to register my app with "docker:myorg/myapp:latest" and then deploy it, I have an error in microk8s :

```
Failed to pull image "myorg/myapp:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to resolve image "docker.io/myorg/myapp:latest": no available registry endpoint: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

It's like microk8s is not looking in my Docker local registry.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's support to resolve Docker images from the private Docker registry. You'd either have to configure the setting as a global property in SCDF or it can be supplied as part of the individual stream deployment.

See: [SCDF + Private Docker Regisrty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_private_docker_registry_2)

Nothing changes in your registration command, however. With the `imagePullSecret` passed correctly, the image should then resolve after a successful negotiation.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I forgot to push my local Docker image in my private local registry. I also replace "myorg" with "localhost:5000" to make it work. I'm not very familiar with Docker. Sorry for these newbie errors ...